# How to showing search after klick next pagination?

Tags: php, codeigniter

First I made `pagination` which is a success and then I made a `search` button. In the first-page `pagination` and `search` are success data can be viewed, but when I search for data on the next page the data can't be viewed. How to show searchable data on the next page?

This is the link in the first page after search:

```
http://localhost/lavaggio/Pegawai/pegawai?keyword=sisil&submit=submit
```

and this is the link in the second page after search:

```
http://localhost/lavaggio/Pegawai/pegawai/2?keyword=annisa&submit=submit
```

**Controller**

```
public function pegawai(){ 
        $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/lavaggio/Pegawai/pegawai';
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->Pegawai_model->count_all_peg();
        $config['per_page'] = 2;
        $config['num_links'] = 2; 
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data['start'] = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $data['keyword'] = $this->input->get('keyword');
        $data['daftar_pegawai'] = $this->Pegawai_model->select_all($config['per_page'], $data['start'], $data['keyword']);

        $this->load->view('templates_owner/header');
        $this->load->view('templates_owner/sidebar');     
        $this->load->view('owner/data_pegawai', $data);  
        $this->load->view('templates_owner/footer');
```

**Model**

```
function select_all($limit, $start, $keyword = null)
    {        
        // $this->db->select('*'); 
        // // $this->db->order_by('date_modified', 'desc');
            $this->db->like('id_pegawai',$keyword);
            $this->db->or_like('nama_pegawai',$keyword);
            $this->db->or_like('no_tlp_pegawai',$keyword);
            $this->db->or_like('alamat_pegawai',$keyword);
            $this->db->or_like('umur',$keyword);
            $this->db->or_like('jenis_kelamin',$keyword);
            $this->db->or_like('username',$keyword);
            $this->db->or_like('password', $keyword);
         // $this->db->from('tbl_pegawai'); 
         // 
        return $query = $this->db->get('tbl_pegawai',$limit, $start)->result();
        // return $this->db->get();
    }     

function count_all_peg()
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tbl_pegawai');
        
        return $this->db->get()->num_rows();
    }
```

**View**

```
*this is search
<form class="d-none d-sm-inline-block form-inline mr-auto ml-md-3 my-2 my-md-0 mw-100 navbar-search">
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
              <form action="<?= base_url('Pegawai/pegawai');?>" method="POST">
            <div class="input-group">
              <!-- <?php $attributes //= array('class' => 'row'); ?> -->
              <input type="text" name="keyword" class="form-control border-0 small" placeholder="Search for..." aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" Value="<?=@keyword?>"> <!--untuk menyembunyikan kode error-->

              <div class="input-group-append">
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
                  <!-- <i class="fas fa-search fa-sm"></i> -->
              </div>
            </div>
            </form>
            </ol>
          </form>

<div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                <thead>
                 <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Nama</th>
                    <th>Nomor Telepon</th>
                    <th>Alamat</th>
                    <th>Umur</th>
                    <th>Jenis Kelamin</th>
                    <th>Username</th>
                    <th>Password</th>
                    <th>Edit</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <?php foreach ($daftar_pegawai as $pegawai) {?> 
                  <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $pegawai->id_pegawai;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $pegawai->nama_pegawai;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $pegawai->no_tlp_pegawai;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $pegawai->alamat_pegawai;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $pegawai->umur;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $pegawai->jenis_kelamin;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $pegawai->username;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $pegawai->password;?></td>
                    <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="<?php echo site_url('Pegawai/edit_pegawai/'.$pegawai->id_pegawai);?>"> <i class="fas fa-fw fa-edit"></i>Edit</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-danger" href="<?php echo site_url('Pegawai/delete_pegawai/'.$pegawai->id_pegawai);?>"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-trash"></i>Delete</a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <?php } ?> 
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
*the pagination
           <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: If the pagination without search works then the error could be that you're not taking search into account when calculating total rows. This might help - https://makitweb.com/pagination-with-search-filter-in-codeigniter/

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution to your problem. You need to set `$config['reuse_query_string'] = true;`. It will carry the existing query string.

For more detail look at [here](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/pagination.html#customizing-the-pagination)